# VBA - Create custom function to check if string is contained within an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, if-statement

I am trying to check if the string in the current cell matches a whole string found in the array, however for some reason the Function always throws an error (im guessing) because the "If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, arr, 0)) Then..." Always gets skipped.

Here is the code I have so far for the function and the method calling it.

```
Function IsInArray(v As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, arr, 0)) Then
        IsInArray = True

    Else
        IsInArray = False

    End If

End Function


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'--- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET -- LABOR WORKSHEET --'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Private Sub LaborTab_Setup(ByVal SheetNameString As String, ByVal JPNum As String, _
                           ByVal OID As String, ByVal SID As String)

    Dim PasteRow As Variant
    Dim LaborListString As String
    Dim MainRange As Range, Cell As Excel.Range
    Dim MainSheet As String, LaborCraftArray() As String
    Dim JobPlan_Number As String, OrgID As String, SiteID As String

    JobPlan_Number = JPNum
    OrgID = OID
    SiteID = SID
    MainSheet = SheetNameString

    'Lists all of the possible LABOR Craft Codes in a single string.
    'Seperated by only "," and no spaces!
    LaborListString = "OPER,INST,SERV,PAINT,SANDB,ELEC,BOILM," & _
             "SCAFF,WELD,RIGGER,INSUL,CATLYS,REFRA,ENG,QAQC,WATCHF,INSP,PIPEF," & _
             "MECH,XRAY,RVTECH,HYPRO,MACH,PIPEF"

    'Splits the string of Labor Crafts assigning each Craft Code to a spot within an array.
    LaborCraftArray = Split(LaborListString, ",")

    Sheets(MainSheet).Activate
    Range("D2").Select

    'Sets Range for Worksheet containing ALL information
    Set MainRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    'Keeps Track of what line to paste info in
    'Does not increase if the Craft was not found in the array
    PasteRow = 2

    For Each Cell In MainRange
        If IsInArray(Cell.Value, LaborCraftArray) Then


            'JOBLABOR.JPTASK
                Sheets(MainSheet).Select
                Range("A" & Cell.Row).Select
                Selection.Copy


            'Updates the PasteRow variables value in order to paste the copied information to the correct line
                PasteRow = PasteRow + 1

        End If

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please consider to delete all the `.select` and `.activate` if they're not needed, since they could always lead to problems. Also why not simplify your search function in:

```
Function IsInArray(v As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

Dim Check As Boolean

For i = LBound(arr) to UBound(arr)
    If v = arr(i) Then
        Check = True 
        Exit For
    End If
Next

IsInArray = Bool

End Function
```

Handling errors is mostly frustrating and could lead to problems